# How to set file access when selecting via the Google Drive Picker API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive Picker API to "attach" files in my app, but is it possible to set access permissions when a file is selected? (e.g. prompting the user to set it to public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the sharing within the File Picker, then I think the answer is no.

This might help though https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app

Comment: What do they mean by "The user has installed your app"? This is for a web app, btw.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/install 
It means your app is integrated with the Drive UI

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting "Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/share...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." when trying it out. I've set the app id and the Open URL correctly (AFAICT).

Comment: Have you configured your referrer URL in the API COnsole?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant due to how confusing the Cloud Console is, so here are 2 screenshots of where I *think* referrer URL could mean. (still getting the SAMEORIGIN error btw after setting them) http://i.imgur.com/egj9Es3.png http://i.imgur.com/0MFKKSF.png

Comment: It's the javascript origin one

Comment: So yeah, doesn't seem to work. I've removed the "*" in the screenshot, thinking that was it. The App ID mentioned in the article is this number here http://i.imgur.com/Y48NARW.png right? And not the AppEngine project id?